# Export SQL table into text file using SQLCmd with <~> as field separator

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a windows batch file to export data from an `SQL` table to a .txt file with `<~>` as field separator.

I tried to escape with `^` still i am unable to export with `<~>` as field separator, below is the command

`sqlcmd -S YourDBServer -d DB_NAME -E -Q "select mcc_code, 1, name, address, domain, mask from table" -o "tableName_date.txt" -s"^<~^>" -W -h -`

how should i escape? Please help.

Comment: have you tried `^<~^>`? Escaping only works in case there are no surrounding `""`...

Comment: the fact is that `-s switch` uses the very first character as column separator, regardless how many chars you write after it

Comment: Thank you,  elzooilogico yes, -s switch allows only one character. I am using bcp to achieve the same.